# Is it possible to load in a KeyStore using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, jfilechooser, jsse

Hi I am developing a chat program that will use keystores in java. At the moment you can load the keystore through a command line argument in the terminal. The program would be started as follows `java Chat /keystore TEST.keystore`  - main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arg_length = args.length;
    switch (arg_length) {
    case 1:
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/keystore")) {
            keystore = args[1];
            File test = new File(keystore);
            if (!test.exists()) {
                displayHelpInformation();
            }
        } else {
            displayHelpInformation();
        }
        break;
    }
    Chat my_server = new Chat(port);
}
```

Keystore is declared as a string and as you can see below I load the keystore from the given input stream.

```
private SSLServerSocketFactory getSSLServerSocketFactory() {    
    SSLContext ctx = null;
    try {
        KeyManagerFactory kmf;
        TrustManagerFactory tmf;
        KeyStore ks;
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
        // Returns a SSLContext object that implements the specified secure
        // socket protocol.
        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        // returns keystore object of type Java KeyStore
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), password);
        kmf.init(ks, password);
        tmf.init(ks);
        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
}
```

What I am trying to do is allow the user to select the keystore using JFileChooser in the main window instead of using command line arguments? Is this possible? I am concerned about the fact that the keystore has a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want with JFileChooser... I've been using it a lot lately, it's not perfect, but it's useful.

My Example would go like this:

```
public boolean openFile() {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
// OPTIONAL : if you would like to make the choices only *.keystore
        FileFilter ff = new ExtensionFileFilter("KeyStore Files", new String[] { "keystore" });
        jfc.setFileFilter(ff);
// END OF OPTIONAL
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(".")); // base folder
        jfc.setDialogTitle("Choose a KeyStore");
        int jfcReturnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(parentFrame);
        if (jfcReturnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            // sourceFile here would be the *.keystore file selected
            File sourceFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Openning a file cancelled.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You can change the return type to File if you want the method to return the File, but I usually just send true or false as notification of success or failure.

As for the password part. If you use `ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), password);` with success, then passing to it the File you got from JFileChooser will work as well.

---

OPTIONAL CLASS:

```
class ExtensionFileFilter extends FileFilter {
    String description;

    String extensions[];

    public ExtensionFileFilter(String description, String extension) {
        this(description, new String[] { extension });
    }

    public ExtensionFileFilter(String description, String extensions[]) {
        if (description == null) {
            this.description = extensions[0];
        } else {
            this.description = description;
        }
        this.extensions = (String[]) extensions.clone();
        toLower(this.extensions);
    }

    private void toLower(String array[]) {
        for (int i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0, n = extensions.length; i < n; i++) {
                String extension = extensions[i];
                if ((path.endsWith(extension) && (path.charAt(path.length() - extension.length() - 1)) == '.')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how I would do this **As for the password part. If you use ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), password); with success, then passing to it the File you got from JFileChooser will work as well.**

Comment: Well, JFileChooser will give a File Object. This can be used in any way you like. So just pass that File Object to your standard way of loading the keystore and it should work just the same as if it was passed as an argument. `file.getAbsolutePath();` would give you a String of the path to the file in question... If you want to talk about it more, join http://collabedit.com/y96km